# How to implement click event for setdisabledstate text box in angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, controlvalueaccessor

I'm using `controlvalueaccessor` for my reactive form where i'm having one text box which is disable one for that i'm using `setdisabledstate` function .

Now i need to write a click event for that text box ,I stuck in that part , whether it is possible  or not.Kindly suggest me some solution.
                                                                                                      .html

```html
    <label>{{label}}</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" 
        [value]="val"
        [disabled]="disabled"
        data-col-index="0"/>
```

.ts

```js
    import { Component, OnInit, forwardRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
    import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, } from '@angular/forms';

    const CUSTOM_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CDisplayComponent),
      multi: true,
    };

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-c-display',
      templateUrl: './c-display.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./c-display.component.css'],
      providers: [CUSTOM_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
    })
    export class CDisplayComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {

      @Input() label: String;
      @Input() value: String;
      val: String;
      private disabled: boolean = true;
      private onChange: Function;
      private onTouched: Function;

      constructor() {
        this.onChange = (_: any) => { };
        this.onTouched = () => { };
      }

      ngOnInit() {
      }
      writeValue(obj: any): void {
        this.val = obj;   
        if(this.value != undefined){
          this.val= this.value;
        }

      }

      registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        this.onChange = fn;
      }

      registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
        this.onTouched = fn;
      }

      setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
      }
    }
```

Comment: not button ,simply need click event like on touching the text box need to open another page,but in my case the text box is disable one.

Comment: So even when the button is disabled you want click event on text box  element?

Comment: Yes you're correct,i need that functionality

Comment: Can't you add click event on app-c-display component?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one help you

```js
 set isDisabled(value: boolean) {
     this._isDisabled = value;
     if(value) {
      this.form.controls['name'].disable();
     } else {
        this.form.controls['name'].enable();
      }
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" [value]="val" [disabled]="isDisabled"' name="name" [(ngModel)]="name"/>
```

Comment: actually i want to write click event for that disable text box,like if i click that text box i need to route to another page

Answer (score 0):

```js
private disabled = false;     
isDisabled():boolean {
         return this.disabled;//should get updated control state changed dynamically
        }
setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
 this.disabled = isDisabled;
      }
```

```html
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [value]="val" [disabled]="isDisabled()" name="name" [(ngModel)]="name"/>
```

Comment: When this isDisabled() will called ?

Comment: called automatically by angular if disabled value changed

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```js
fileInputClick = (event) => {
   alert("sss")
    // Do what you want
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div (click)="fileInputClick($event)" >
    <input type="text" disabled="disabled">
  </div>
</div>
```